# I am using "dompdf" for invoice (pdf) downloading in codeigniter.. not allow to add any extra row?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, dompdf

My code snippet:

```
    function invoicepdf()
    {
        $order_id   =   $this->uri->segment('3');
        $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));

        $select  =  'ci_order_status.name as status_name ,ci_manual_order.*';
        $where   =  array('order_id'=>$order_id);

        $this->db->join('ci_order_status','ci_order_status.status_id=ci_manual_order.status_id');
        $this->db->order_by('ci_manual_order.order_id DESC');

        $this->data['details']    =     $this -> home -> getDataFromTableWithWhere('ci_manual_order',$where,$select);

        $html = $this->load->view('myaccount/print_invoice', $this->data, true);
        //echo $html; die;
        pdf_create($html, 'invoicereceipt');         
    }

        function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
        {
            require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

            $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
            $dompdf->load_html($html);
            $dompdf->render();
            if ($stream) {
                $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
            } else {
                return $dompdf->output();
            }
        }
```

Above pdf downloding functionality working fine.. but in above code i am using "print_invoice" view file for invoice..

But now i want to add two extra rows in above receipt/view-file (table).. then this code is not working properly.. if i add any extra row in view file & run the functionality.. browser gets hanged..

In codeigniter:

why dompdf not allowing any extra row in view file??

How can i add extra rows in receipt??

plz suggest the changes??

Comment: DOMPDF can have problems if the design (usually table cells) spans more than one page. The solution in many cases will be to create a design that will not stretch a table cell over to the next page. If you're not dealing with table cells, then post your HTML so we can look at it. See here for more info: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/98

Comment: thanks.. i made changes in design & its worked.. its also going on next page properly..